# Time complexity of Recursive functions

Tags: python, time-complexity

hi I'm having trouble finding the time complexity of these 2 recursive functions:

```
def func_1(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return True
    return func_1(n // 2)
```

an this one

```
def func_2(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return
    x = 0
    for i in range(n):
        x += 0.1
    return func_2(n // 2)
```

I think that the first function time complexity is O(log n) but I'm not sure. as for the second function I have no idea

Answer (score 2):

The first example is indeed O(log n) -- every time you call `func_1` you halve `n` until it hits zero.

In the second example, the complexity is O(n log n). You still have the halving of `n` like before, but for each iteration you also process the whole of `n`.

Comment: hi but n is getting halved each time so the loop wont run on the original n wont it?